# How display multiple lines in the "Mac Terminal" using "console.log" with the command line "Local heroku" in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, macos, heroku, console.log

To launch my application,

when I use the command line : "node index.js" => my Mac Terminal displays all lines from an object.

When I use the command line : "heroku local" => my Mac Terminal displays just only one line from an object.

**How can I display several lines on my Mac Terminal when I use "heroku local" ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, this is only a guess here, but there may be a difference between versions of Node which is causing this behavioural change. Nonetheless, you can do a pretty-print in node using JSON.stringify:

```
var a = {foo: "baz", bar:{a: "b"}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 4))
```

With any luck that will make them look the same. This is because JSON.stringify allows for a space formatting value as it's [third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Also, for better object inspection **util.inspect** allows better rending of information about objects, nested to a arbitrary degree (and including better error meta info which seems to be lost in a lot of stringification.

```
var util = require('util');
var a = {foo: "baz", bar:{a: "b"}}
console.log(util.inspect(a));
```

However, I think util varies between nodeJS implementations, so you may see some variation. [See here](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) for the Node v5 implementation (latest at time of writing)